# onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) is never called

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-intentservice

I have a BluetoothLeService which is called from IntentService. BLEService works fine until it connects. After it establishes the connection with iBeacon, it calls ;

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
```

Everything is okay so far but after that point in spite of mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices() returns true, onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) is never called.

**---------------------UPDATE----------------------------------**

On debug it shows newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED but it does not really connect. It shows same result for fake ids which are belong to unexist devices.

**-------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is my callback

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };
```

My Broadcast Receiver

```
 // Handles various events fired by the Service.
        // ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED: connected to a GATT server.
        // ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED: disconnected from a GATT server.
        // ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED: discovered GATT services.
        // ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE: received data from the device.  This can be a result of read
        //                        or notification operations.
        private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {


                } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {

                } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                    // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                    mBluetoothLeService.getbattery();
                } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                    batteryLevels.add(Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRAS_DEVICE_BATTERY)));
                }


            }
        };

    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }
```

My BluetoothLeService class

```
        import android.app.Service;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Binder;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.util.Log;

        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Set;
        import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Service for managing connection and data communication with a GATT server hosted on a
 * given Bluetooth LE device.
 */
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
    public final static String EXTRAS_DEVICE_BATTERY = "EXTRAS_DEVICE_BATTERY";

    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);

    private static final UUID Battery_Service_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    private static final UUID Battery_Level_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        Log.v(TAG, "characteristic.getStringValue(0) = " + characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_BATTERY, characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    public void getbattery() {

        Set pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        BluetoothGattService batteryService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(Battery_Service_UUID);

        List<BluetoothGattService> servicesList;
        servicesList = getSupportedGattServices();
        Iterator<BluetoothGattService> iter = servicesList.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            BluetoothGattService bService = (BluetoothGattService) iter.next();
            if (bService.getUuid().toString().equals(Battery_Level_UUID)){
                batteryService = bService;
            }
        }
        if(batteryService == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery service not found!");
            return;
        }


        BluetoothGattCharacteristic batteryLevel = batteryService.getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
        if(batteryLevel == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery level not found!");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);
        Log.v(TAG, "batteryLevel = " + mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel));
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
     *
     * @param address The device address of the destination device.
     *
     * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
     *         is reported asynchronously through the
     *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     *         callback.
     */
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }
        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    /**
     * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
     * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
     * callback.
     *
     * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
     */
    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
     *
     * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
     * @param enabled If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.*/

    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                              boolean enabled) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
        if (Battery_Level_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
     * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
     *
     * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
     */
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. The real problem is connection. It shows like it is connected but it is not, I tried to connect with false address and it still connected.

After I added

```
mBluetoothGatt.connect();
```

at the end of connect method of BluetoothLeService.java it started to work.

Thanks for helps Vikram Ezhil

Comment: in Dell Venue tab its firing onServiceDiscoverd without calling mBluetoothGatt.connect(); but in lenovo after i add mBluetoothGatt.connect(); it got fired 
But its showing status as 133 any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the service

@ **your_Main_Actiivty**

```
Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), your_Service_class.class);

// Starting the service
bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**Updated:**

Update your code as per the below, connect() method should be called from inside onServiceConnected()

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mBluetoothLeService =   ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService(); 

         if (!bluetoothHDPService.initialize()) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
             finish();
         };

         // connnect method() should be called here and not anywhere else
         mBluetoothLeService.connect("1C:BA:8C:21:60:E9"); 
    };

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mBluetoothLeService = null;
    };
};
```

**2nd Update**

It seems you never called setCharacteristicNotification method. Add the below line of code after
**mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);**

```
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(batterLevel,true)
```

Comment: Yes I bound the service.

Comment: was connect() method called from your Main Activity via service?

Comment: It is called in the same class with Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), your_Service_class.class);

// Starting the service
bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

Comment: can you show me your service connection code which you used in your main activity?

Comment: As I referred it is called from Intentservice instead of main activity. Here is the codes: mBluetoothLeService.connect("1C:BA:8C:21:60:E9"); and these are the codes where mBluetoothLeService is defined; private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
                mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

Comment: if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                    return;
                }
                // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                mBluetoothLeService = null;
            }
        };

Comment: I tried,still works in exact same way, connects but cannot discover services. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Okay, i just did a entire trace on your code and one thing that got my attention was at your Broadcast receiver your have called the method mBluetoothLeService.getbattery(); during ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED. In that method you have called only readCharacteristic, but not setCharacteristicNotification. Add this code mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(batterLevel,true) after mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);. That should do the trick. Have updated this as well above!!

Comment: since onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) is never called, it does not go into ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED case. I tried it for any case, but it is still same.