# BLE gatt.discoverServices() returns true but onServicesDiscovered is never called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an Android app for a school project, I just need to be able to communicate with a device using BLE.

I am at the point where I am connected to the GATT server of my device, but i can't find any services as `onServicesDiscovered` callback is never called.
I have followed the instructions of [android - BLE gatt.discoverServices() returns true but Callback never fires - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764878/ble-gatt-discoverservices-returns-true-but-callback-never-fires/76048704#76048704) and [android - onServicesDiscovered never called while connecting to GATT Server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434555/onservicesdiscovered-never-called-while-connecting-to-gatt-server) but it doesn't makes it work...

I also replied to one of these posts, here is my message :

> I am currently getting the same issue, without beeing able to correct it with a delay. I even called `gatt.discoverServices()` using a button to ensure the connection to be done before searching for services but doesn't work either.
> When I press this button, I get this [`gatt.discoverServices()` log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XflMu.png).
> Have you got any idea on how to deal with it ?
> **Edit**: the following two permissions are in my manifest but I can't manage to let the user enable them, they seem to be not granted at start. **BUT**, all the methods that seemed to need these permissions at this point are working fine (`bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` or `device.getName()` for instance).

```java
Manifest.permissions.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
Manifest.permissions.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
```

Any idea on how to deal with it ?

Comment: What is the Android version of the device you use for testing? The two Bluetooth permission you have mentioned are Android 12+ only.

Comment: My phone is on android 8. I removed these permissions and the program "works" as mentionned before (connecting to GATT is ok, but discovering devices gets me the same logs as [gatt.discoverServices() log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XflMu.png)). I found an exemple program [(See BluetoothLeGatt project)](https://github.com/VoltXd/connectivity-samples) which works well and seems to work approximatly like [my project](https://github.com/VoltXd/MyFirstApp). Any idea ?

Comment: The permissions you use are exclusive to Android 12+ devices. So on Android below 12 you have to query different permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67722950/150978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More debug allow me to see that `onServicesDiscovered()` was called, the real issue was with the `BroadcastReceiver`. Before calling the function `registerReceiver`, I forgot to add the action `ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED` in the IntentFilter. Adding this action fixed the problem.